# Power Bi DAX Issues with TopN when using a date. I'm only seeing the top N for the range of dates. I want to see top N BY WEEK

Tags: powerbi, dax, greatest-n-per-group, powerbi-desktop, measure

Essentially I am using this measure:
Measure = calculate([Total],KEEPFILTERS( TOPN(10, ALLSELECTED('Users'[User]), [Total],desc) ))

I've also tried:

UserClicks = RANKX(ALLSELECTED('Users'[User]),[Total], ,DESC)

Both technically work. However, when I use a date as a small multiple, I am getting the top TEN FOR whatever timeframe. Aka, if I select 6 weeks of data, I am getting the top 10 over those 6 weeks like this:
[image]

You notice how some of the weeks are blank? This is because they are a top ten for the 6 weeks, but did not have entries that week. I am trying to output a similar graph but keep the top 10 PER week.

I hope I explained this correctly. Thank you for your time and help with this!!